# add character to json android

Tags: android

I have the following problem. I must send the following json

```
tosend = {"tn": 37537.6015625,
"d":
{"fa": 12, "nt": 37537.6015625, "ca": 1, "a": 4692.2001953125, "p": 4692.2001953125, "a": 1116861},
"tb": -27182.3984375}.
```

For this I used the method json.put () and then json.acummulate ("d", JsonObject).

as I can do to give me the following result

```
 tosend = {"tn": 37537.6015625,
"d":
[{"Fa": 12, "nt": 37537.6015625, "ca": 1, "a": 4692.2001953125, "p": 4692.2001953125, "a": 1116861}
], "Tb": -27182.3984375}.
```

when I add two data fuciona "[". I need to send it this way because I can not change the script on the server.

I used to use the json.append.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create Current jsonObject as :

```
//Create main json object
JSONObject json = new JSONObject();

//Create d JSONArray
JSONArray dJsonarray = new JSONArray();

// Create JSONObject
JSONObject djson = new JSONObject();
// put value inside d json object
dJson.put("fa", "12");
dJson.put("nt", "37537.6015625");
dJson.put("ca", "1");
dJson.put("a", "4692.2001953125");
dJson.put("p", "4692.2001953125");
dJson.put("a", "1116861");

// put JSONObject to json Array
dJsonarray.put(dJson);    

//put tn key-value in json object
json.put("tn","37537.6015625");
//put d json object name-value in json object
json.put("d",dJsonarray);
```

and no need to call [JSONObject. accumulate](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject.html#accumulate%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object%29) because this method *Appends value to the array already mapped to name*  . because your main json string which u want to send to server has only jsonObject

Comment: @user2014065 : can u tell me more why it's not working because this is code according to your question

Comment: @user2014065 : as in question you are saying *I must send the following json*

`tosend = {"tn": 37537.6015625,
"d":
{"fa": 12, "nt": 37537.6015625, "ca": 1, "a": 4692.2001953125, "p": 4692.2001953125, "a": 1116861},
"tb": -27182.3984375}.` then my answer create same structure json object which u want to send .then where is issue ?

Comment: ok, my fault. I must send the following string  tosend = {"tn": 37537.6015625,
"d":
[{"Fa": 12, "nt": 37537.6015625, "ca": 1, "a": 4692.2001953125, "p": 4692.2001953125, "a": 1116861}
], "Tb": -27182.3984375}. and I could not add character [ . i tried with         json.put("d", "["+detallePedidojson+"]"); and nothing